# Why won't this python regex compile?

Tags: python, regex

I have a python script with the following regular expression to grab two strings (that may contain escaped quotes) from NSLocalizedString macros in my code:

```
NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)"\s*\)
```

It works fine in RegexRx and matches exactly as expected...

[image: RegexRx]

...however, when I try to add it to my python script like this...

```
localizedStringComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)"\s*\)', re.DOTALL)
```

... it fails with the following message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../localization_scripts/sr_genstrings.py", line 21, in <module>
    localizedStringComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)"\s*\)', re.DOTALL)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

It seems like python needs extra escaping somewhere but I have no idea where. If I add extra backslashes to the last pair on the line, like this...

```
localizedStringComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\\\]*)"\s*\)', re.DOTALL)
```

...it runs without the error but then doesn't match anything. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a raw string literal:

```
re.compile(r'NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)"\s*\)', re.DOTALL)
```

because backslashes have meaning in a regular Python string *too*. A raw string literal (a string literal prefixed with `r`) ignores (most) escape sequences that Python supports.

See [The Backslash Plague](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) in the Python Regular Expression HOWTO.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
localizedStringComment = re.compile(r'NSLocalizedString\(@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)",\s*@"(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)"\s*\)', re.DOTALL)
```

Note the small r in front of the regex string. This indicates that it is a raw string. (See also http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)